# Email Validation in iOS is not called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In iPhone App How to Add Email validation on UITextField?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

//Valid email address

if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:userMailTextField.text] == YES) {
}
else{
NSLog(@"email not in proper format");
}
```

Comment: where are you writing this code, in textfield delegate??

Comment: your if condition is totally wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can check against UITextField like txtemail

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    //Valid email address
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:txtemail.text] == YES)
    {
    }
    else
    {
     //email id is not proper 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code,`[ClassName validateEmail:txtEmail.text error:&alertMessage]`

```
+ (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) myEmail error:(NSString**)error
{
    BOOL isValid = FALSE;
    if ([Validations isValidData:myEmail])
    {
        NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];  
        if (![emailTest evaluateWithObject:myEmail])
        {
            *error = @"Please enter vaild email address";
            isValid = FALSE;
        }
        else 
        {
            isValid = TRUE;
            *error = @"";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        *error = @"Please enter email address";
        isValid = FALSE;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```